# Integral with varying limits

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

In an exercise to solve problems using dominated convergence theorem, I came across this:

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^n \bigg(1-\frac{x}{n}\bigg)^n \log(2+\cos(x/n)) \ dx
$$
My attempt: I rewrote the integral as follows
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} f_n\  g_n\  h_n \ dx
$$
where $f_n(x)=\bigg(1-\frac{x}{n}\bigg)^n, \ g_n(x)=1_{(0,n)}(x), \ h_n(x)=\log(2+\cos(x/n))$.
Thus $\lim_{n} f_n(x)g_n(x)h_n(x)=e^{-x}. 1_{(0,\infty)}.\log(3)$.

But I'm unable to find a dominator $F(x)$ such that $f_n(x)g_n(x)h_n(x) \leq F(x)$ and $F(.)$ being integrable.

Comment: Isn't it true that $(1-x/n)^n \le e^{-x}?$

Comment: No it isn't, but $(1 - x/n)^n \chi_{[0,n]}(x) \le e^{-x}$ is true.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, thnx.

Comment: In the context of the OP, $f_n(x) g_n(x) \le e^{-x}$ on $(0,\infty)$ so $e^{-x} \log 3$ is an appropriate majorant.

Comment: $(1-x/n)^n\leq e^{-x}$ is also true !

Comment: @UmbertoP: Thanks.

Comment: @Surb: Yeah, it's true because $e^{-x}$ is always positive and if you are outside $(0,n)$ it's automatically true.

Comment: Is the claim that $(1-1000/2)^2 < e^{-1000}$? I find that surprising.

Comment: @UmbertoP. : Yeah I think we need the characteristic function for the limit.